# How to reserve disk space for electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

For my electron app, I'd like to make sure that writing to it's database (IndexedDB) still functions, even when the user's hard  drive is full for some reason. Is it possible to somehow reserve disk space for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, pre-insert rows and then update them later, rather than insert them when you need them. Mind, depending on the IndexedDB implementation, this may or may not work (depending on how updates are done).

So, you'll want to test it first.